# Toggle editing tool block when apply filters

Tags: qgis, filter

I'm using QGIS 2.18 on Windows 10,
When I apply a filter on a layer, the editing tool comes into disabled.

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

That's expected behavior - if you have a filter present on a layer, it's no longer editable. You need to remove the filter in order to edit the layer.